# Convert select to input when defined option is selected

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, forms, select

I would like a particular option in a select statement to convert to an input when selected, as it is meant to function as a sort of "other" to allow the user to input custom text. Here's what I have so far:

HTML (I am hoping to have the last option with value 0 be converted if selected):

```
<select class="text-muted mt-4 text-muted" style="position:absolute;font-size:85%;left:16px;top:16px;border:#CCCCCC 1px"  id="taskLabel" placeholder="Choose Tasklist...">
         <?php 
           $tasklists = $db->query('select id,name from tasklist where deleted = 0 AND userid = 0 OR userid = (select id from user where email = ? order by userid desc,name)',$_SESSION['email'])->fetchAll();
           foreach ($tasklists as $list)
           {
             echo '<option class="small" name="'.$list['name'].'" value="'.$list['id'].'">'.ucfirst($list['name']).'</option>';
           }
           ?>
          <option style="border-bottom:1px dashed #CCCCCC;margin-bottom:1px"></option>
          <option class="small" id="addNewTasklist" name="add_new" value="0">Add new tasklist</option>
        </select>
```

JS:

```
if (("#taskLabel").children("option:selected").val() == "0")
        {
          $("#addNewTasklist").replaceWIth('<input name="newTasklist id="newTasklist">');
        }
```

Any help to point me in the right direction would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: You are missing a `$` for `$("#taskLabel").child...` That should have thrown an error in your browser dev tools console if it is not a copy paste issue into this post. No mention that you checked errors or not

Comment: You can not use `replaceWith` an option by an input type="text" inside the `select`. You have to `replaceWith` the whole select with `input if val() == 0`

Comment: @charlietfl This does not seem to a `typo` issue only. Please correct me if i am wrong.

Comment: @AlwaysHelping Your point about swapping input and option is definitely accurate so there is more than a typo issue. Not even sure what best workaround would be for OP other than display the input above/below/beside the select. Turning into an XY problem too

Comment: I added the $ and changed the label to refer the entire select ( $("#taskLabel") ), but that did not resolve the issue.

Comment: @user882134 Yes, Sure!. Please refer to the second comment i posted!

Answer (score 0):

I was able to figure this out successfully with the following JS changes:

```
$("#taskLabel").change(function(){
    if($("#addNewTasklist").prop("selected",true))
    {
        $("select#taskLabel").replaceWith('<input name="newTasklist" id="newTasklist" placeholder="Add New Tasklist"><i class="fas fa-times tasklist-remove-icon text-muted"></i>');
    }
```

I added an 'x' icon to revert back to a select if needed:

```
$(document).on('click', '.tasklist-remove-icon', function(){
     $('.tasklist-remove-icon').remove();
     $("input#newTasklist").replaceWith('<select class="text-muted mt-4 text-muted" id="taskLabel" placeholder="Choose Tasklist..."><?php $tasklists = $db->query('select id,name from tasklist where deleted = 0 AND userid = 0 OR userid = (select id from user where email = ? order by userid desc,name)',$_SESSION['email'])->fetchAll();
           foreach ($tasklists as $list)
           {
             echo '<option class="small" name="'.$list['name'].'" value="'.$list['id'].'">'.ucfirst($list['name']).'</option>';
           }
           ?></select>');
        });
```